# What is equivalent in Spring XML configuration for @Resource List<SomeType> someTypes?

Tags: java, spring

I have bean injection like this:

```
@Resource
List<SomeType> someTypes;
```

Is it possible to delcare such bean in XML configuration, so it will be empty list? This is required for testing environment.

In other words, how to do

```
@Bean
public List<SomeType> someTypesFactory(){
   return Collections.emtpyList();
}
```

in XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define like this. The snippet is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd">

    <util:list id="someTypesList" value-type="com.project.SomeType">

    </util:list>
```